# YUI 3: Setting request headers with DataSource.IO

Tags: ajax, json, authentication, yui, datasource

I need to retrieve a JSON resource which requires HTTP Basic authentication. Therefore, I need to set a request header for a DataSource.IO object.

I see that the IO utility itself supports a `header` key in its configuration object. However, since I'm new to YUI, I can't figure out how to set this configuration value through the mediation of DataSource.

To be clear, I don't need help constructing a correct Authorization header, just getting YUI to send the headers I construct. Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set IO config values via [DataSource.IO](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/DataSource.IO.html)'s ioConfig config object:

```
var ds = new Y.DataSource.IO({
    source: "script.php",
    ioConfig: {
        method: "POST",
        data: "foo=bar",
        timeout: 1000
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I saw that documentation, but I guess I was in a dazed stupor or something and didn't understand it.